# Python subprocess calling mysqldump with .cnf file fails when shell=False

Tags: python, mysql, linux, subprocess

What I want to do is call mysqldump to make a backup of a database table.

I have assembled a list of command line arguments, where db and tbl are the database and table names, respectively, and cnf is a properly formatted mysql configuration file (containing host, user and password),

```
args = ["mysqldump","--defaults-extra-file="+cnf,db,tbl]
print " ".join(args)
```

The output of the print is,

```
mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=dbserver.cnf test mytable
```

When I copy/paste the above line into the (bash) shell, it works.

When I use subprocess.Popen, the command fails,

```
import subprocess as sp
...
proc = sp.Popen(args, shell=False, stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE)
stdout = proc.communicate()
retcode = proc.wait()
if retcode>0: print "error",retcode
```

But when I join the args together, and call subprocess.Popen with shell=True,
the command works as desired,

```
cmd = " ".join(args)
proc = sp.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE)
stdout = proc.communicate()
retcode = proc.wait()
if retcode>0: print "error",retcode
```

Further investigation reveals that the first command does not seem to use the user/password credentials from the config file, but the second variant does.

Responses to other questions about subprocess.Popen make it clear that one should avoid the shell=True, but the first approach above fails.

Can anyone identify what I am doing wrong above?

Comment: are you on windows or Linux? if you're in windows, type `where mysqldump` and post the result. On Linux, I think it's `which mysqldump`. Also, can you post the output returned by `Popen` when `shell=False`, the one returned by `communicate()`

Comment: If you want to be sure you are splitting right the command you can use the `args = shlex.split('mysqldump --defaults-extra-file= ..whatever.. ..... ')`. And by the way maybe you want to check the `subprocess.run`. It do the same without the wait and communicate methods. The results will be the same although and not fix the problem

Comment: linux. which mysqldump yields /usr/bin/mysqldump, subprocess.Popen(["which","mysqldump"]) yields same.